# How do I get the Acquaint app code (a pre-built Xamarin app from xamarin.com) to work?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

There are code issues I have no idea where to start on fixing straight out of the gate after downloading and opening Acquaint. I have current versions of Community VS 2105 and Xamarin.

If someone wants to give it a shot, here is the address where the download is at: https://www.xamarin.com/prebuilt?utm_source=visualstudio&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=ios-prebuilt&utm_campaign=vs

I have restored the NuGet packages for the project, and I don't know what else to do. I read that I should should delete things out of the Xamarin folder, and then restart? But I'm not clear about what to delete.

I have not been introduced to solving these kinds of errors. Thanks ahead of time to anyone trying to help me figure it out.

UPDATE: I restarted Visual Studio once and I got these two errors: "C:\Users\GAR\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embed‌​ded./ doesn't exist." AND "C:\Users\GAR\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embed‌​ded\classes.jar doesn't exist." ... Then I restarted Visual Studio for the second time, and those two errors disappeared, and now [here is the screenshot of errors and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU5c7.jpg) the only red error is "No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scrollFlags' in package 'com.xamarin.acquaintforms'  Acquaint.XForms.Droid C:\Users\GAR\Desktop\acquaint\‌​app-acquaint-master\Acquaint.XForms\Acquaint.XForms.Droid\Resources\layout\toolba‌​r.axml ", and the only IDE* yellow Warning error is "IDE0006   Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled."

This message 
"The 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar' element is not delcared" 
shows when hovering over the 'code' android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: the very first error says that there are missing packages.  Have you checked each project in the solution to verify that all the packages are restored?

Comment: further, the two IDE* errors lead me to believe that Xamarin has not been properly installed

Comment: How would I properly install Xamarin? I followed the directions?